# Convert jQuery mobile application navbar to Android apk menu

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have converted a jquery mobile webpage to android app using phonegap.

The problem is that mavbar/menu in Android is cutting the menu words. i.e. What we do -> What we... .Can u suggest me a better way to create a menu without damaging the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) is the better way to make your application work well on all screen resolution